# Count rows and filter and then delete filtered rows with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Can any one tell me how to count the total number of rows in an Excel spreadsheet and then pass the value dynamically?

Instead of the value of 2691 for the last row, I want to pass `lastRow` variable when setting the filter. Then I want to count the total rows again and then delete those rows from spreadsheet.

```
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$P$2691").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    "=ABC", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=XYZ"
Rows("285:285").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the question:

> Instead of the value of 2691 for the last row, I want to pass lastRow variable..

The specific answer is to set the `Range` to filter using the `lastRow` variable that you set when you counted the rows in the range, e.g:

```
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Try the code below - each step is clearly commented.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    'set sheet reference
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'turn off autofilter
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    'get last row
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'set range to filter
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C" & lastRow)

    'set filter
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=ABC", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=XYZ"

    'delete visible rows
    rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

    'show remaining rows by removing autofilter
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Robin, Can you tell me how to apply pivot chart also please.. i recorded the macro but when i run am getting errors. 
'Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable4" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select'

Once the pivot chart generates,i want to create one more spread sheet using grand total.

Comment: @SivaReddy - that sounds like a new question - why don't you start a new one?